# if 'a' or 'b' in L, where L is a list

Tags: python

I am having trouble with the following logic:

Lets say I have a list:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

Both items are in the list...

```
if ('a' or 'b') in L:
    print "It's there!"
else:
    print 'No sorry'
```

prints `It's there!`

---

Only the first item is in the list...

```
if ('a' or 'd') in L:
```

prints `It's there!`

---

Neither item in the list...

```
if ('e' or 'd') in L:
```

prints `No sorry`

---

**Here's the confusing one.** Only the *second* item in the list...

```
if ('e' or 'a') in L:
```

prints `No sorry`

---

I do not understand why this is not registering as a true statement. How does this generalize to an **or** statement with *n* conditionals?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's break down the expression:

`('e' or 'a')` will first check if `'e'` is True. If it is, the expression will return `'e'`. If not, it will return `'a'`.

Since all non-empty strings returns `True`, this expression will always return `'e'`. This means that `if ('e' or 'a') in L:` can be translated to `if 'e' in L`, which in this case is `False`.

A more generic way to check if a list contains at least one value of a set of values, is to use the `any` function coupled with a generator expression.

```
if any(c in L for c in ('a', 'e')):
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this instead:

```
 if 'a' in L or 'b' in L:
```

If we want to check if *all* these of this "items" are in the list, `all` and a generator comprehension is your friend:

```
items = 'a', 'b', 'c'
if all(i in L for i in items):
```

Or if *any* of these items are in the list, use `any`:

```
if any(i in L for i in items)
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings (except an empy string) will always evaluate to `True` when they are evaluated as a boolean. While evaluating with `or/and` both will return `True`, but there is a little difference between them:

```
print 'a' or 'b'    # Output:  a
print 'a' and 'b'   # Output:  b
```

`or`: will return the first string
`and`: will return the last string

When you do

```
if ('a' or 'b') in L:
```

, it will check `'a' or 'b'` which is `'a'` and then check if `'a'` is in `L`. Something similar happens with the other cases (based on what I explained before).

So when you do

```
if ('e' or 'a') in L:
```

, `'e' or 'a'` will evaluate to `'e'` and therefore it will print `'No Sorry'`, because `'e'` **is not** in `L`.

What you must do is compare whether elements are in the list **separately**:

```
if 'a' in L or 'b' in L:
if 'a' in L or 'd' in L:
if 'e' in L or 'd' in L:
if 'e' in L or 'a' in L:
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to the output you're getting is that `and` and `or` in Python always evaluate to one of their operands -- generally the one that had to be evaluated last to determine the truthiness of the operation:

```
1 or 2   # Returns 1 because since 1 is true, there's no need to
         # evaluate the second argument.
1 or 0   # Returns 1, same thing.
0 or 2   # Returns 2 because 0 is false, so we need to evaluate
         # the second arg to check whether the operation is true.
0 or ""  # Returns "" (both 0 and "" are false).

1 and 2     # Returns 2 because for an and operation to be true,
            # both its operands need to be checked for truthiness.
0 and 2     # Returns 0, because we know that if the first operand
            # is false, so is the whole operation.
0 and None  # Still returns 0, we don't even need to check the
            # second operand.
```

So when you're evaluating `(1 or 2) in [1, 3, 5]` (where in truth you want `1 in [1, 3, 5] or 2 in [1, 3, 5]`), what really happens is `(1 or 2)` is evaluated to `1`, and your operation becomes `1 in [1, 3, 5]`.