# Conditional "or" operator in Python is not validating properly

Tags: python-2.7

```
status= None
if 'Up' or 101 in status:
    print "Inside If statement"
else:
    print "Inside Else Statement"
```

The code flow goes inside "If" loop and prints "Inside If Statement". The status is None actually and by reading the code it should print "Inside Else Statement". I can modify the validation part and make it execute inside else statement. But i would like to know how "True" is returned for this condition

```
if 'Up' or 101 in status:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Python are falsy, which is to say an empty string (`''`) is equivalent to `False`, and others are `True`.

Your condition is evaluated as (brackets only for explanatory purpose)

```
if ('Up') or (101 in status):
```

And since `'Up'` is always `True` it will always go inside the `if` block.

You can instead write:

```
if 'Up' in status or 101 in status:
```

Or a more generic way with `any` would be:

```
if any(x in status for x in ('Up', 101)):
```

You can find more answers for this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344842/if-a-or-b-in-l-where-l-is-a-list-python)

Comment: Thank You for your explanation.  This part made me clear. if ('Up') or (101 in status):

Comment: `if 'Up' or 101 in status` also evaluates properly for me, instead of `if 'Up' in status or 101 in status:`